# Can't load any NuGet Package - Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reference, package, nuget

Any package I try to load in my solution, I get always the same error.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'LinqKit, Version=1.1.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc217f8844052a91'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'LinqKit, Version=1.1.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc217f8844052a91'
```

In this case is LinqKit, but it's the same with elasticsearch, PdfPig and others. Never had this kind of problem before.

The installation goes fine, and I get the references in my solution as in the image below:

[image]

Thanks for any tips! C# net.core 3.1

edit: This is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Test.Libraries\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="LinqKit" Version="1.1.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Test.Public.DAL">
      <HintPath>..\..\Test.Libraries\netcoreapp3.1\Test.Public.DAL.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you show your `.csproj` file?

Comment: Hm, can you also show your web project’s `.csproj` where the error is coming from? Do you have your library properly referenced?

Comment: What do you mean with web project? The error is coming from the backend side....Yes my library is correctly referenced, the point is only on this project I get this kind of error, on any other one every package works fine. I'm gonna crazy for that.

Comment: Your screenshot with the error clearly shows that you are running an ASP.NET Core web application. But the csproj you showed is _not_ an ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: try to [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and then restore nuget again.